# How prove this $\sin{t}=t-\frac{\sin{(\theta t)}}{2}t^2$

Tags: calculus

show that:there exsit $\theta\in(0,1)$,such that

> $$\sin{t}=t-\dfrac{\sin{(\theta t)}}{2}t^2\tag{1}$$

the book say this is **Taylor formula**

But I kown that Taylor formula, there exsit $\xi$ such that
$$\sin{t}=t-\dfrac{-cos{\xi}}{3!}t^3$$

How about prove $(1)$? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taylor's formula in general says

> Let $f \colon [x_0, x_0+t] \to \mathbb R$ be $(n+1)$-times differentiable. Then there is a $\theta \in [0,1]$ such that 
>   $$ f(x_0+t) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(x_0)t^k + \frac{1}{(k+1)!}f^{(k+1)}(x_0+\theta t)t^{k+1} $$

Apply this with $k=1$ and $x_0 = 0$ here.